# MySQL transactions with PHP - queue statements?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, transactions

This thought just occurred to me, and I have no idea if it's crazy or not.  No examples I've found online are set up this way.  I'm building a wrapper around MySQLi (or maybe PDO) and I'm just in the designing stages.  This is for a personal project to learn more about OO design, so while I appreciate the thoughts of using Doctrine or Propel or something, no thanks.  This question is to help me learn some better design principles; I know the code will work, but from a design perspective, am I running wild?

This will be my first time working with transactions in PHP with MySQL.  I understand the basics - use a try/catch statement, commit at the end, rollback if there's an exception.  But in the middle, here is a list of the statements to execute:

(pseudo-code)

```
try
{
  $db->startTransaction();
  $db->query('...');
  $db->query('...');
  $db->query('...');
  $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $exc)
{
  $db->rollback();
}
```

What if the `query` method adds the queries to an internal array?  Then the `commit` method does this type of try/catch internally and tosses out another exception.  Like this (again, pseudo-code):

```
$db = new AwesomeDBWrapper('...');
$db->query('...');
$db->query('...');

try
{
  $db->commit();
} catch (AwesomeDBWrapperCommitException $exc)
{
  echo $exc;
}
```

The `commit` method could start the transaction, query, commit or rollback.  It can work, but my question is really about design - is that *too* much?

There are pitfalls with my pseudo-code - it doesn't take into account a read vs. a write to the database, so there should really be a `query`, `update`, `insert`, `delete`, etc. methods.

Does this make any sense from OO design perspective?  It seems nice from a coding perspective - you can write your statements outside the try/catch in the normal code, and then execute later.  It also seems a little annoying in that regard too ...

Comment: Queues don't make much sense. PHP isn't threaded, and db calls will block until the db operation completes. Since you have to wait until the previous operation completes before you can start a new one, there's no point in having a queue.

Comment: I'm not worried so much about threading and blocking here - the point is more for the code and it's usability/reusability.

Comment: Queuing doesn't make much sense when the transactions are sequentially dependent. e.g. insert a row, then that new rows' insert id to generate the next sequence. You'll probably find that most query sequences you'll come across are of this sort, and just stuffing queries into a queue doesn't much sense, even if it's not for threading purposes.

Comment: That makes more sense - I didn't consider fetching the insert ID.  Good thought, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Does it make sense from an OO design perspective? Kinda. Does it make sense from a database usage perspective? Definitely not.**

As pointed out by Marc B in a comment, the database already queues the operations anyway, as they are blocking calls*.  They will happen in that order.  Just let it do it's thing.

**: although you CAN make non-blocking calls, it isn't usually the case.*

Comment: As I responded to Marc, I'm not concerned about application performance necessarily - though I certainly don't intend to greatly diminish performance.  It's more for the code itself and how a programmer can use it.  If it's not going to have an affect on performance, then does it make sense from a usage perspective?